# rake function in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I am very new in ruby-on-rails. I have doubt in rake. `create` function is create a new db. After that, we want to run some commands like

```
rake db:load
rake db:data:load
rake db:schema:load
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

But why we want to run this cmds after create the db and what function of the about cmd.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rake -T` to get the description of each task:

```
$ rake -T | grep db
rake db:create                                # Create the database from config/database.yml for the current Rails.env (use db:create:all to create all dbs in the config)
rake db:drop                                  # Drops the database for the current Rails.env (use db:drop:all to drop all databases)
rake db:fixtures:load                         # Load fixtures into the current environment's database.
rake db:migrate                               # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false).
rake db:migrate:status                        # Display status of migrations
rake db:rollback                              # Rolls the schema back to the previous version (specify steps w/ STEP=n).
rake db:schema:dump                           # Create a db/schema.rb file that can be portably used against any DB supported by AR
rake db:schema:load                           # Load a schema.rb file into the database
rake db:seed                                  # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:setup                                 # Create the database, load the schema, and initialize with the seed data (use db:reset to also drop the db first)
rake db:structure:dump                        # Dump the database structure to db/structure.sql. Specify another file with DB_STRUCTURE=db/my_structure.sql
rake db:version                               # Retrieves the current schema version number
```

I this what you were asking about?

**EDIT:**

You can read more about what migrations are for here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

**EDIT 2:**

`rake db:migrate` allows you to update the DB schema in a "sane" way: you can create a new migration (read the guides!) and add a new column for example, add an index, rename a column, etc. - migrations allow you to "travel" back and forth in "time" - you can run the migration and rollback it later.

When you generate a new migration:

`$ rails g migration add_new_column_to_some_table` you will be able to run `rake db:migrate` later on to apply to changes you want (of course you have to write the body of this generated migration).

I STRONLY advise you to read the guides though :)

**EDIT 3:**

`add_column :users, :price, :float`, for example, will add `price` column to the `users` table, the type of the column will be `float` (`float` isn't a best idea to store money related things BTW!). This column will be `NULL` by default.

**EDIT 4:**

Information about which migrations were run is stored in `schema_migrations` table: running migration for the first time will add a new record in this table with `version` of this migration (date + some random numbers from the name of the file). Rollbacking a migration will remove this record. Running a migration twice will not have any effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my confusion is y we want to run `migrate`. Can u give me some hints.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What does "y we want to run migrate" mean?

Comment: @TomekWałkuski I believe "y" == "why".

Comment: @user1598053 - updated the answer, it should help you if you are a novice in this matter

Comment: Why we should run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: If I ran two times `rake db:migrate` cmd, Now what will happen? Is over right made in database?

Comment: I have made another update. I strongly advise to read the guides though :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, db:migrate doesn't destroy existing data you have in your database. so running migrations and that rake task allows your data to exist from changes you make.

### Workflow in words

1. You `create` an empty data base.
2. You will want to add a table of data for your first model into the database. This is done by editing a file in `db/migrate`
3. Now you want a second model, so you create your model and edit the migration file in `db/migrate` that was created for you
4. The easiest way to update your database without destroy any of the existing data, is to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. This adds the contents of the second migration file into the db and won't hurt existing data.

### Example workflow after creating a project:

1. `bundle exec rake db:create:all`
2. `bundle exec rails generate scaffold Users name:string email:string`
3. `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
4. At this stage, `bundle exec rails s` and go to `localhost:3000/users/new` and create a new user.
5. `bundle exec rails generate scaffold Posts title:string body:text`
6. `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
7. Back in your browser go to `localhost:3000/users` and you should still see the user you created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I ran rake db:migrate instead of point no:6. Now what will happen?

Comment: not sure if anything would happen but if you had a bunch of gems not found without running bundler, ti would ask for the gems.